# Why doesn't VC++ 2010 Express require stdio.h in this program but gcc++ does?

Tags: c++

I have the following code

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void WaitForEnter()
{
    while(1)
    {
        if('\n' == getchar()) 
        {
            break;
        }
    }
    return;
}

int main()
{
    cout<< "Press Enter to Exit... ";
    WaitForEnter();
}
```

This compiles on Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express and does what I expected.  On Ubuntu using code::blocks and gcc++ 4.7 the build fails with the following `error: 'getchar' was not declared in this scope.`  If I add the line `#include "stdio.h"`, the program compiles and runs with the expected behavior.  Why does this program compile using MVC++ 2010 Express without `stdio.h` but not for code::blocks with gcc++ 4.7 on Ubuntu.

Comment: Are you using precompiled headers (i.e. `stdafx.h`)?

Comment: @Jesse Good I was not familiar with precompiled headers, just did a quick search and yes I am using them, should I turn them off?

Comment: I dont think visual studio will let you compile unless you are including stdafx.h

Comment: Of course MSVC will let you compile without stdafx.h.

Comment: @newToProgramming: Yes, for learning purposes, it is better to turn them off. Pre-compiled headers help to make compile times faster, but that usually only matters for very large projects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With MSVC, `<stdio.h>` is included as a side effect of including `<iostream>`. Look at the preprocessed output, or follow the #include paths in the MSVC file.

Comment: @EitanT: Did you check? I see this path. iostream -> istream -> ostream -> ios -> xlocnum -> cstdio -> stdio.h.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  `stdafx.h` is not necessary (this can be easily verified by running `cl.exe` directly).

Answer (score 2):

The simplest answer is that the standard allows any standard header to include any other header. On the other hand, if you want to write portable code, you should not depend on this, and should include all the headers that are needed for your translation unit.

Answer (score 0):

In visual studio when you make a new project, it includes stdafx.h for you. In this file, it includes:

```
#include "targetver.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
```